# What is the best way to have an array of 2 properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'd like to have an array in javascript that each item contains 2 properties instead of 1, how would that be possible?

The following only adds one property to the item by default:

```
var headerCellWidths = new Array();
headerCellWidths.push(100);
```

this enables me access the item using [0][normalCellWidth]

but I'd like to be able to have e.g. [index][normalCellWidth][firstTemplateCellWidth]

e.g. [0][100][25]

e.g. headerCellWidths.add(100, 25);

One solution is to create my own CustomArray obviously which maintains 2 separate array instances but isn't there a better way?

Thanks,

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. Just make an object with a methods like myObj.add(100, 25), myObj.get(0, 100, 25) and put all logic here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the entries as objects to the array.
Try this:

```
 headerCellWidths.push({normalCellWidth:100, firstTemplateCellWidth:25);
```

You would access the items using:

`headerCellWidths[0].normalCellWidth` and `headerCellWidths[0].firstTemplateCellWidth`